# Caché Object Script Code guidelines

Tags: coding-style, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I work with InterSystems Cache and look for Caché Object Script coding guidelines.
Does someone have any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this [project](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/cos-guidelines). It provides Caché Object Script Code guidelines